# Accessing Data from Data table using for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to get data from data table using for loop. i tried as belows but not working. please help me

```
String GetBelowDataWeekly = "Select EmployeeID from v_Et_EmployeeProfile where DivisionName=N'" + DivisionName + "' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS and PositionName=N'Officer'COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS union all Select EmployeeID from v_Et_EmployeeProfile where DivisionName=N'" + DivisionName + "' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS and DepartmentName= N'None' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS";
SqlDataAdapter adaptGetBelowDataWeekly = new SqlDataAdapter(GetBelowDataWeekly, DBcon.con);
DataTable dtGetBelowDataWeekly = new DataTable();
adaptGetBelowDataWeekly.Fill(dtGetBelowDataWeekly);
for (int i = 0; i < dtGetBelowDataWeekly.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Response.write(dtGetBelowDataWeekly.Rows[i]);
}
```

Comment: First you need to give use more information about exactly what isn't working.  Is it giving you an error, and if so what is the error?  Or is it giving you results that you don't expect? Then give us the actual and expected results.  Finally you really should use parameters instead of concatenating values into a SQL query.

Comment: Thank you sir for your fast response. i need to Response query results from data table.

Comment: The error is "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRow' to data type int."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the first column of the Rows[i].  The first column contains the integer value you're looking for.  So:

```
Response.write((int)dtGetBelowDataWeekly.Rows[i][0]);
```

Comment: Thank you So much. Sir. now i can access it